# glReadPixels from back buffer. Problem with float precision

Tags: c++, opengl, floating-point, precision

I'm trying to get color for my color picker, but I get a float value, that differ from value I stored. For example I set 0.5, but I take 0.498039 (this is the real numbers).
I don't build any FBO and read color from GL_BACK directly:

```
glReadBuffer(GL_BACK);
glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, &color);
```

How can I save precision of floating point value? Is it possible to change GL_FLOAT to another which would save precision? Is it possible to get in &color numbers greater than 1.0?

Comment: Is .39821 an actual result you observed or just a number you made up for an example?

Comment: @EricPostpischil just example. I needed to show the difference between expected and obtained value.

Comment: When asking questions, you should show actual data. It may contain clues about the problem, and fabricated data can mislead people. The number .39821 is not possible to obtain from eight-bit data that is scaled from 0-255 (unsigned eight-bit binary integers) to 0-1 (intensity values), which made me think there might be some other problem here.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Sorry if I confused you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precision is limited by the precision of the frambuffer (back buffer). This precision cannot be set individually and is (most likely) limited to 8 bit per channel. Actually the [Default framebuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Default_Framebuffer) is generated once, when the OpenGL window and [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) is generated.
Thus it makes no sense to read the read the buffer to 32bit float target, because the source buffer just has 8 bits.
Anyway it is possible to render the scene to a named [Framebuffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) where the color plane of the attached [Renderbuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Renderbuffer_Object) has a floating point format (e.g. `GL_RGBA32F`). See [LearnOpenGL - Framebuffers](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers).